# Why does more rotational inertia result in a smaller velocity down an incline?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, rotation

In my physics class we are learning about how objects with greater rotational inertia result in less translational velocity when "rolling without slipping" down an incline. When explained, it is taught that more rotational inertia will result in more rotational kinetic energy being converted from gravitational potential energy. However, increasing rotational inertia decreases angular acceleration and thus decreases angular velocity. Would this lesser angular velocity not result in less rotational kinetic energy, and therefore more translational kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is that once the object has finished rolling down the slope, its gravitational potential energy has been converted into a mix of rotational and translational kinetic energy. Storing energy in rotation in the case of rolling without sliding subtracts from what would otherwise end up as translational kinetic energy in the case of sliding without rolling.